# How to make a JOIN in LINQ to SQL equivalent to Not Equals

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

I've got a table:
Year | Period | Account

During a new period, I'd like to get a list of new accounts and a list of accounts that also existed in the prior period.

Accounts that are also in the prior period:

```
    bs.DataSource = from c in accountsToImport
             join p in accountsToImport on c.Account equals p.Account
             where c.Year == year && c.Period == period
             && p.Year == priorYear && p.Period == priorPeriod
             select c;
    return bs;
```

However, I can't figure out how to get the equivalent of "**not equals p.account**" with LINQ->SQL. The SQL command that does work:

```
select * from tsr_accountsToimport as cper
inner join tsr_accountstoimport as pper
on cper.account <> pper.account
where 
cper.year = 2015
and cper.period = 4
and pper.period = 3
```

Any help to get the LINQ syntax would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try SelectMany instead of join.

```
from c in accounts
from p in accounts
where c.Account != p.Account
```

Comment: according to microsoft it's a crossjoin. Good solution though [How to: Perform Custom Join Operations (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882533.aspx)